# Cross Origin GET Request CORS Error with Data Power

Tags: javascript

I am trying to connect to `Denodo` to pull back information via an `API` call, but I have to go through `Data Power` for security reasons. When bypassing `Data Power`, we are able to successfully retrieve the data from `Denodo`. I have been informed that everything is set up in `Data Power` correctly for the response headers and the configuration is set to allow our web application. Below is the code we use to make the call:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "target URL", true);
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'source URL');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhr.response);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
```

We receive the following error in the console when executing the function:

Access to `XMLHttpRequest` at 'target URL' from origin 'source URL' has been blocked by `CORS` policy: Request header field `access-control-allow-origin` is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in preflight response.

We have tried a variety of different options to get this to work, but we still can't. I've searched the forums for similar issues, and the responses have been tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is the response header that should be set by the backend, whereas you're trying to set it as a request header. What happens if you remove the two Access-Control header lines?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get another error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'target URL' from origin 'source URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: It appears that Data Power is not setting the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` in the response. In order to use `xhr. withCredentials` you need that header set by the server. You can verify it by simply visiting the target URL in Chrome and watch the dev tools (F12) Network tab, click the request and look at the response headers. If it's a third party configuring Data Power (I'm not familiar with) then I would send a screenshot of the response to show the header(s) are missing.